# Zenity gateway Shell parse error

Tags: shell, zenity

I have a probem with Passerelle variable. This code return a error message on the line if ("Passerelle" = "$Blank")

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=$(zenity --forms --title="Informations de connexion"\
     --text="Entrez les informations sur votre connexion a distance"\
     --separator=","\
     --add-entry="Domaine (Optionnel)"\
     --add-entry="Passerelle (Optionnel)"\
OUTPUT_RESULTS=$?
if ((OUTPUT_RESULTS != 0)); then
    echo "erreur sur le formulaire"
    exit 1
fi
Blank=$""
Domain=$(awk -F,'{print $3}' <<< $OUTPUT)
Passerelle=$(awk -F,'{print $4}' <<< $OUTPUT)
if ("$Passerelle" = "$Blank")
then
     Passerelle="$Passerelle"
else
    Passerelle="/g:$Passerelle"
    echo "$Passerelle"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `if ("$Passerelle" = "$Blank")`

```
if [ "$Passerelle" = "$Blank" ]
```

is the correct syntax.